# Evaluating expression from dictionary

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I am trying to build the same discount engine that magento has, just rewriting in python. The rule definition is stored by magento application in the database for the conditions/actions are in php serialized array.
In my database the value is stored in php serialized array, from which I have successfully transformed to dictionary using phpserialize package and then from dictionary to lists to get the expression part.

Sample dictionary is this (Converted from php serialized array to dict):

```
{
'type': 'salesrule/rule_condition_combine',
'aggregator': 'all',
'operator': None,
'attribute': None,
'conditions': {0: {
    'type': 'salesrule/rule_condition_product_subselect',
    'aggregator': 'all',
    'operator': '>=',
    'attribute': 'qty',
    'conditions': {0: {
        'operator': '{}',
        'attribute': 'category_ids',
        'type': 'salesrule/rule_condition_product',
        'is_value_processed': False,
        'value': '1145',
        }},
    'is_value_processed': None,
    'value': '4',
    }},
'is_value_processed': None,
'value': '1',
}
```

The converted list from the above dict:

```
[['>=', 'qty', '4', 'AND', ['in', 'category_ids', '1145']]]
```

This above list is generate through these functions(Taken from eevee):

```
def operatorSymbol(self, operator):
    if operator == "{}":
        return "in"
    elif operator == "!{}":
        return "not in"
    elif operator == "<":
        return "<"
    elif operator == "<=":
        return "<="
    elif operator == ">":
        return ">"
    elif operator == ">=":
        return ">="
    elif operator == "==":
        return "=="
    else:
        return operator

def aggregatorConvert(self, aggregator):
    if aggregator == "any":
        return "OR"
    else:
        return "AND"

def expression_tuple(self, query):
    if query.get("attribute"):
        exp = []
        exp.append(self.operatorSymbol(query.get("operator")))
        exp.append(query.get("attribute"))
        exp.append(query.get("value"))
        return exp
    else:
        return []

def format_serialized(self, query, counter):
    counter = counter or 0
    ex = self.expression_tuple(query)
    conditions = query.get("conditions")
    if conditions:
        for i in query.get("conditions"):
            if ex:
                ex.append(self.aggregatorConvert(query.get("aggregator")))
            ex.append(self.format_serialized(query.get("conditions")[i], counter + 1))
    return ex
```

Now, I have several of them, many has nested conditions.

I would like to operate on the dict/list part so that I can build a generic evaluation function that will take the parameters needed for the conditions to evaluate to either true or false.
For example:
The above List defines: If quantity of products in category_ids 1145 is greater than equal to  4 then evaluate to true.
This is single expression as the List starts at >= and ends at 1145.

How can I do this ?
I have tried this:

```
_operators = {
    '<': operator.__lt__,
    '<=': operator.__le__,
    '>': operator.__gt__,
    '>=': operator.__ge__,
    '{}': operator.__contains__,
    '!{}': lambda x, y: y not in x,
    '==': operator.__eq__,
}

def process_condition(self, query):
    if query.get('aggregator') == 'any':
        agg = any
    else:
        agg = all

    conditions = []
    if query['operator']:
        op = self._operators[query['operator']]
        value = int(query['value'])
        attr = query['attribute']

        conditions.append(lambda data: op(data[attr], value))

    for subquery in query.get('conditions', {}).values():
        conditions.append(self.process_condition(subquery))

    return lambda data: agg(cond(data) for cond in conditions)
```

Which takes the dict and then evaluates, like so:

```
cb = process_condition(query)
print(cb(dict(qty=5, category_ids=[1145])))
print(cb(dict(qty=1, category_ids=[240])))
print(cb(dict(qty=5, category_ids=[420])))
```

Which evaluates to True, False, False respectively. 
But when the dict has two category_ids in the key value or a more complex one it gives compilation error.
More sample data is in this gist: [Sample Dict and corresponding List as well](https://gist.github.com/shadow-fox/3f0fbb6d46e3bde4c8ac)

Which one to pick to do this kind of evaluation Dict or List? If Dict, how can I overcome the more complex ones like mentioned in the gist ? If List, how can I do that ?

Comment: Just as a side note: you may want to have your expression looking something like `['AND', ['>=', 'qty', '4'], ['in', 'category_ids', '1145']]`, at least to get consistent.

Comment: Let me add the code that transforms the dict to list.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers The conversion is correct with respect to the functions defined. Please look into the Gist that I have supplied.

Comment: what is your end goal? why use php serialized arrays in the first place?

Comment: @dnozay PHP serialized array was stored in the database, I am just converting to the dict/list. Goal to evaluate the conditions that are present in the dict/list with the variables defined.

Comment: @PranayaBehera that is just repeating what I read in the question - which is still very confusing. why is it stored this way in the first place? It is also unclear what you are trying to do or build. Are you trying to rewrite a database query engine in python?

Comment: @dnozay: It is stored by magento application. I am trying to build a discount engine. For that the discount conditions/actions are stored in database in php serialized array. Which I then fetch from the database and then the all the steps I did are in the question.

Comment: @dnozay The same discount engine that magento has, just rewriting in python.

Comment: that would be very helpful context information in the question.